# How can I auto run ccleaner on mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I've set up a .bat file in windows to auto run ccleaner in the background using the

`"C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner.exe" /AUTO`

line of code. How can I do this for Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Comment: This is actually not a programming question - but you can use the Automator to run a certain task automatically. Pretty intuitive user interface.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go. Can you run multiple tasks at once with automator?

Comment: I've posted an answer and additionally answered your second question. Maybe you'd like to accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a programming question - but you can use the Automator.app to run a certain task automatically. Pretty intuitive user interface.

In addition to your second question: You can add multiple tasks (from predefined actions to custom AppleScript stuff) in one "run cycle". Just launch the program, it's quite easy to use, you'll see.

Comment: I've tried using automator + terminal in combination to have autorun work, but so far I've only managed it to trigger ccleaner opening, but not autorunning. Is there a 'run' command or something similar with terminal's syntax?